# Tridion - Move component to another folder

Tags: tridion, tridion2009

I want to move one component from one folder to another folder already created.

```
while (textReader.Read())
{
    textReader.MoveToElement();
    Component comp = tdse.GetComponent(textReader.GetAttribute("ID"), constant_Publication, true, -1);
}
```

I try looking for `comp.Move` but it doesn't exits. 
Also, i saw that in `comp.Info.Path` there is the path, but if i try to modify it i have the following error :

> Error 7 Property or indexer 'Tridion.ContentManager.Interop.TDS._Info.Path' cannot be assigned to -- it is read only.

What can i do to move the component?

Comment: Please consider posting this question on http://tridion.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you are using TOM rather than TOM.NET

You need to perform a paste action with the folder you want to get the new item into

Something like

```
objFolder.PasteItem(comp, 1, false)
```

The first parameter is the item you want to paste, the second is an enumerator (EnumTDSCutCopyAction - 1 is cut (move), 0 is copy ) to say if you want to *Copy and Paste* or *Cut and Paste*, and the final one is whether you want to assert a unique name.

In TOM.NET there is a `RepositoryLocalObject.Move()` method.

Answer (score 1):

It appears that your GetObject() method call has some missing arguments.  The templating manual states the folloowing:

```
Public Function GetObject( ByVal URI As String, ByVal mode As TDSDefines.EnumOpenMode, Optional ByVal contextPublication As Variant = TDSDefines.URINULL, Optional ByVal filter As TDSDefines.XMLReadFilter = XMLReadNull ) As Object
```

However it appears that the second argument you're passing in is a publication ID, not the EnumOpenMode.  Pass "OpenModeEditWithFallback" as the second argument to the function to get the component in write mode and you should be able to use the Move function on it afterwards.

Also, please consider posting further Tridion questions on our new Tridion side http://tridion.stackexchange.com